# How to show d3.js no data message?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to show no data message instead of empty graphs.

Adding text like this:

```
if (requests.length === 0) {
  svg.append('text')
    .classed('noData', true)
    .text("No Data");
}
```

and styling it like this:

```
.noData {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But at best my graph is showing like this:
[image]

How to add no data message to d3.js bar chart?

Comment: I usually check for data before plotting svg. If no data then simply display a fancy image filling up the entire space